# Chat paste is too long

Tags: feature-request, chat

When I paste into chat a multi-line comment, its naturally inserted into a `<div class=full>` and the text truncated.  It seems like its `max-height: 400px` is too long.  Given that its purpose is to make sure a single comment doesn't flood the chat, a more viable size would be `200px`.

Here is a picture as an example of the current behavior
[image]

I realize this is a bit nitpicky, but it is frustrating that the block dominates my screen when its designed specifically not to.